# Data exchange through FIROS fails

Tags: ros, fiware, fiware-orion

On a computer, 2 ubuntu virtual machines are installed. On one of them there is another virtual machine with Fiware-orion Context broker. Both VMs have ROS.

I am trying to make a simple publisher-subscriber ROS program, that sends a message from one VM to another one through FIROS(firos is installed and configured). The problem is that the message from a publishing VM is being sent to FIROS(or it is better to say, the topic is shared through FIROS), but somehow it is not being achieved by the subscribing VM, and therefore I cannot see the message being sent.

We are using the local network so there shouldn't be an issue with port forwarding. Moreover, using `rostopic list` it is visible that it has `fiware`topics on both VMs running. 
Can it be, that the issue lies in using Virtual Machines rather than 2 separate PCs?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.
There were 2 problems - first, the IP address of the server in `config.json` must be of the machine where the FIROS is running, not where I wanted to send it.
2 problem, the FIROS has to be launched last, after all other nodes are being run. Therefore it is able to subscribe to those topics and send the data. I was running FIROS first and therefore failed to subscribe, because there were nothing to subscribe to at that particular moment.